# Upgrading TortoiseGit - Close Windows Explorer

Tags: tortoisegit

There is a hotfix version of **Tortoise Git** and my PC refuses to install it. It keeps saying **Windows Explorer** is running, even when it is not showing the **Task Manager**.

Is there any other way I can get this upgrade to install?

## Update

I decided to start Windows 10 in **Safe Mode** so we can be sure that nothing is running. Yet it still would not perform the upgrade (with **Administrator** privileges):

[image: Error]

I used **Task Manager** and I could not see **gitdll.dll** in the list of running processes.

Comment: the Windows shell is also explorer.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried both types of installer:

- Hotfix
- Full

And both were refusing to work. I then occurred to me that all the icons were flashing on my desktop and it was stuck. This was consistent behaviour.

So I decided to switch of my **Star Dock** [Fences](https://www.stardock.com/products/fences/):

- Right-click Desktop and select Configure Fences:

[image: Menu]

- Scroll-down to the bottom of the pop-up window and un-tick **Enable Fences**:

[image: Disable fences]

- Close the window.

Now I was able to install the hot-fix. Interestingly the installer was only complaining about the **Windows Explorer** still running and did not list Fences.

I hope this helps any others who have struggles upgrading TortoiseGit.

Comment: this is something we can't know. Good to see that you got it working now

Comment: I have the same issue, and am not running fences

Comment: @Russell look for the [reply from the developer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62193212/1466046)

Answer (score 2):

1.download hotfixes

2.restart windows (don't open any apps after restart)

3.run Task Manager (from windows bar)

4.run hotfix from menu of Task Manager -- File -- Run new task

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue; I solved it by running:

```
listdlls64 -d "c:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\gitdll.dll"
```

and used task manager to manually kill all processes that were using the dll, including `explorer.exe`. This seems entirely unnecessary but it's what worked for me.

Why so many processes (including `LogonUI.exe`, `OpenWith.exe`, `splwow64.exe`, etc.) attached to `gitdll.dll`, is unknown, and seems like an issue that can be solved. We know that explorer uses that dll, but you would think the installer/updater would expect that and be able to work around it.

Answer (score 1):

In 2.10.x hotfixes there was a bug in the hotfix updater which was unable to offer a restart for replacing `gitdll.dll` during a restart cycle. A failure to replace this file caused lots of crashes (cf. https://tortoisegit.org/issue/3599).

Please download the full installer for TortoiseGit and install it (https://tortoisegit.org/download/; there might be a warning regarding a possible downgrade, this can be ignored).

**Generally**

The .MSI installer and newer hotfixes offer two options when installing:

1. Try to restart open processes - this might fail as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61026137/3906760 based on some third-party software.
2. Requiring no closing/restart of open programs but the replace the file on reboot. This should work in any case because the file is replaced before starting any programs using it.

Comment: Since it is now "working" for me (shutting down Fences) do I need to still do what you said?

Comment: When the update installed cleanly and you don't experience crashes on TortoiseGit Log then there is nothing to do.

Comment: If the next update fails then I will install the full version next time.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully installed disabling AVIR and allowing the installer to close as much as it wants